# Android run method/code after UI shows

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to load the UI, then once the user can see the UI start some other code. I want to run that code on the UI thread.

```
   onCreate(){
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);//myLayout starts with a blue background
        myLayout = (LinearLayout)....
        myLayout.setBackgroundColor(red);
    }

    onViewDisplayed(){
    //myLayout is visible and shows a red background while the UI thread is blocked by Thread.sleep()
       Thread.sleep(5000); 
       myLayout.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
    }
```

One way I can get it to work is by doing this:

```
onCreate(){
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);//myLayout starts with a blue background
        myLayout = (LinearLayout)....
        myLayout.setBackgroundColor(red);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);//runnable calls onViewDisplayed() above
    }
```

This way isn't what I want, though. Because if I change postDelayed to 100 ms, then `myLayout` does not show the red background before `Thread.sleep(5000)`, so all I get to see is the yellow background.

How can I do this with a guaranteed execution AFTER the layout displays without having to specify any delay, if it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the `ViewTreeObserver` listeners. What I would suggest is an `OnPreDrawListener`.

```
myLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        // Remove the listener so that it is only invoked once
        myLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

        // Post a Runnable to be executed on the *next* animation frame
        ViewCompat.postOnAnimation(myLayout, myRunnable);

        // Return true if this first frame should be drawn
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in onResume where you can start your postDelayed. And you can save in savedInstanceState if you only want to do that once.

Comment: `postDelayed` in `onResume` has the same affect. If I make the delay too small, then nothing shows on the screen until it is done.

Comment: Can you describe the behaviour that you are experiencing...with 5 secs you are not able to see the 2 background? Remove this from the post delayed Thread.sleep(5000); and put the 5000 secs as time of the handler

Comment: Can't you set a background asynctask with a timer on when to update UI?

Comment: In your case you can use the postDelayed, it will work nicely :)

Comment: If I have the handler delay 100 ms, then it hangs for 5 seconds showing a blank white screen then updates with the UI I set and a yellow background. I do not want to have to specify a certain timer/delay, thus `postDelayed` will not work.

Comment: The sleep is really very bad because you are blocking everything. If you use this 5 secs in the postDelayed is really better. But I don't understand which is the expected behaviour. Anyway remove the sleep and use the 5 secs in the handler. Instead of 100, put 5000 and try.

Comment: I wouldn't actually call `Thread.sleep(5000)` in production code. I am trying to make it so that the UI operation in `onCreate` (set background red) will display on screen, then immediately after, the 2nd UI operation will run. And if the 2nd UI operation must block, say if some idiot (me) calls `Thread.sleep(5000)`, then at least you will see a red background while the UI Thread is blocked.